# Не могу выдернуть нужный <a> с помощью PHPQuery

Tags: php, html, парсер, dom, phpquery

Создаю новый dom с ссылки и пытаюсь выдернуть оттуда все элементы  но на выходе получаю 0 объектов хотя тем же simple html dom спокойно дергаю их.
Кусок который надо выдернуть выглядит вот так:

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="123-link-here"><span title="title-123-here" class="thumb" style="background-image: url(//blablabla.com/bla.jpg)"></span></a>
```

В идеале хотелось бы получать на выходе чистую ссылку из href.Пробовал делать так:

```
$uro = phpQuery::newDocument($url);
foreach ($uro->find('a.thumbnail') as $picpage){
$clear = $picpage->attr('href');
var_dump($clear );
```

Но результат, как я отписал, просто нулевой.Может я что-то делаю не так?
С помощью simple html dom делаю find('a[class=thumbnail]') и все за секунды находит.

Comment: удостоверьтесь, что `newDocument` и правда принимает ссылку как параметр, ибо то что описано в документации требует контента а не ссылки.

Comment: я передаю в newDocument выход с cURL, даже делал отдельно вывод cURLа и там все нормально работает.

Comment: может `pq($picpage)->attr('href')` ? итерации цикла то есть вообще?